# jQuery AJAX return undefined instead of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My AJAX request:

```
$.ajax ({
  url: "http://plserver.esy.es/map_server.php?num=1",
  onsucces: function (data) {
    console.log (data);
  }
});
```

At this url server return string, but when i try call function in console it return object with parameter responseText (i need this parameter). But how i can get it?

Please, help me, guice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `onsucces`? There's a typo

Comment: `onsucces` should be `success`

Comment: When i try to do it in console it return me responseText, but in function it return me undefined.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
       url: "http://plserver.esy.es/map_server.php?num=1",
       type: "POST",
       success: function (data) {
          console.log (data);
       }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is get `responseText` from the `data` object returned, can you not use:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "http://plserver.esy.es/map_server.php?num=1",
       type: "POST",
       success: function (data) {
          console.log (data.responseText);
       }
 })
```